# Files out of Git control

Tags: git, github

I use git to manage my projects locally. 
Lately I also started using git to manage a fork of someone else project and I got into a particular situation, and I would like to receive advise on this.

**The situation**

I forked someone else github project "particular project" into my own github repository. Later I cloned into my local machine using github desktop. 
So I have the following file structure:

```
LocalRepos/theProject/(here filesof the project)
```

So the folder "theProject" is where .git is, therefore that is the folder that is git controlled. In it there are the files for the project (source code, project file etc)

I opened the project in visual studio, made a new topic branch, made changes, commited them, build them. Everything going fine. git status give me a working tree clean.

Then I decide to create a sample project that will use this project inside *the same solution*. So I add a new project.

The problem starts here. Now I have the following file structure

```
--LocalRepos-----theProject--
             |---sampleProject--
```

I know that maybe I should have initially put "theProject" inside an additional parent folder so as to create there the sample project, and git init in the parent folder but I don't have much experience using github desktop (always use the console) and it was desktop the one that initialize git for me.

So as you can see, I have some files inside sampleProject that although part of the solution are not git controlled. So they obviously don't appear as files to commit.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What was your reason for wanting two separate projects to be managed under the same Git repo?  My advice would be to just create separate repos for the two projects.

Comment: Well, the original project was a dll. I want to contribute by making an application that successfully uses that dll. (I also corrected the dll source because it didn't originally worked)

Comment: If the two projects are only related vis-a-vis their build outputs, then this is not a reason for them to be in the same repo.  Only if the source files are shared should they be in the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a separate git repository for `sampleProject`. You can do this from the command line by `cd`ing to the `sampleProject` folder then type `git init .`. (You might also be able to do this from GitHub for Windows, but I am unfamiliar with it.) Then do `git add .` and `git commit -m 'Initial commit'` (or whatever message you want).

I suggest treating `theProject` as a separate library. You should only commit changes to it directly if they make sense as part of that project and especially if they are changes which you can contribute back to the original developer with a pull request.

Comment: Well, yes I wanted to contribute to the original project (a dll) by first correcting a bug (already done) and second creating a sample that uses it (that is sampleProject)

Comment: @KansaiRobot In that case, it makes sense to include the example project in the same repo. You can simply move the `sampleProject` folder into the `theProject` folder. I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, its suggested project and directory structure, or the community's recommended practice for its project files. With other IDEs, I generally list project files in my `.gitignore` file so that they never are added to git.